# create a trigger to update values

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have these two tables

- Project (projID,TotArticles)
- Article (prodID,ArticleID)

How can I create a trigger to update by 1 the total amount of article every time someone published an article on it?

```
CREATE TRIGGER Art_Up
AFTER INSERT ON Article
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE Project
    SET TotArticle = TotArticle + 1
    WHERE paperID = NEW.PaperID;
```

However, it gives me this error  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";"

Comment: What's `paperID`? I don't see a column called `PaperID` in your table definitions.

Comment: The Oracle PL/SQL Reference has [a whole chapter devoted to Triggers](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS179). I suggest you read it, as it will help understand and fix these simple syntax errors.

Comment: oracle block must have minimum `BEGIN` and `END`

Answer (score 0):

You messed some names, once you write `projID`, once `prodID`, and in your trigger it is `paperID`. Also trigger has no `begin` ... `end;`. And you did not handle adding articles where `projID` does not exist in table `project`. You could check it at first or use `rowcount` after update and if it is 0 then use `insert`. More simple is to use merge.

```
create or replace trigger art_up after insert on article for each row
begin
  merge into project
  using (select :new.projid projid from dual) src
  on (project.projid = src.projid)
  when matched then update set totarticles = totarticles + 1
  when not matched then insert (projID, TotArticles) values (:new.projid, 1);
end;
```

It works, I tested some basic inserts, but it is not recommended at all, because:

- it's a bad idea to keep logic in triggers,
- triggers can be droppped, disabled and then this information may be misleading, false,
- we are slowing insert operations,
- this trigger does not handle `delete` where you should decrement total number of articles.

Instead of trigger use simple view:

```
create or replace view vw_project as select projID, count(1) total from article group by projid;
```